# JQuery show hide with unordered list: need to add dynamic text / hide function

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have an unordered list where I hide any additional list items if more than 3. After that I invoke a JQuery function that puts in a "show more" link at the bottom and toggles any additional list items to show.

However, I'm a bit stuck, I'd like to convert the show link to "Hide" once all list items are showing and clicking on that then hides the additional list items and then the link changes back to "Show more..." again.

Here is the code I have so far that works to expand and show the additional list items.

```
 $('ul li:gt('+index+')').hide();
    $('ul').append('<li class="more"><a href="#">Show more...</a></li>');
    $('ul li.more a').click(function() {
    $('ul li.more a').remove();
    $('ul li:gt('+index+')').show();
    });
```

Note I am not stuck on this code, if there is a better way do implement the entire show / hide code, that's fine.

I wrote a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TQXQD/4/) with the code I have so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here jquery `toggle()` function comes in handy - you can attach to event handlers that will be called every other time element is clicked. Use `text()` to change text of the link (which should't be a link if you don't plan a fallback - use span instead)

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TQXQD/6/).

Comment: Works great, thanks. I like the solution, it seems pretty elegant.

Answer (score 3):

There you go sir :)
Fixed and running well!

http://jsfiddle.net/TQXQD/7/

Comment: This works great, thanks but I do like @Litek's solution below.